# Reverse order of posts not working

Tags: wordpress

Here's my HTML for an archive page:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<nav>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'Main Nav Menu')); ?>
</nav>

<div id="main-content-archive">

<h5 class="inner_text_shadow">Archive</h5>

<div id="clear-box">


<?php query_posts( array(
  'posts_per_page' => 16,
  'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ), 
));
    ?>


    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> 

<?php    $bg_image = post_thumb( get_the_post_thumbnail() );?>  

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><div class="post-bg-archive" style="background: #777777 url(<?php echo $bg_image;?>);">

        <div id="title-bg">
            <div class="transparency"></div>
            <div class="archive-title"><h98><?php the_title(); ?></h98></div>
        </div>

</div></a>  <!-- END post-bg -->

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2>Not Found</h2>

<?php endif; ?> 

</div> <!-- END post_class function -->


<div id="archive-nav"><h12><?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/nav.php' ); ?></h12></div>

</div> <!-- END main-content -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It's not actually an archive page btu modified front page that has more posts showing and a grid view.

The only thing missing here is the reverse order of posts. I want my archive to start with the oldest post. I've read all over and found a PHP code for reversing order but I can't seem to input it correctly.

This is the code that I used:

`<?php query_posts($query_string . "&order=ASC"); ?>`

Depending on where I put it, it either:

1. messes up something and I get a PHP error
2. does nothing
3. instead of showing a 4x4 grid, it shows 1 box that leads to `localhost/archive` i.e. the page that I'm on already.

I also tried resetting `query` and using the aforementioned code after that but that gave me the 3rd version of the problem (also mentioned above).

So, how to get a reverse order of posts at this page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php query_posts( array(
  'posts_per_page' => 16,
  'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )).'&order=ASC');?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it reverses the order but now I only get first five posts and an option to see older posts but when I click "Older posts" link I get the same five posts.
I had that problem with my home page so I used `''paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 )` but that doesn't help here.